How can I make a provider script for an extension to connect it with Web Apps?
I have created an unpacked extension that is working fine I want it to be injected and be able to connect it with apps like MetaMask wallet does.
I have created a provider.js script to do it. I want to know if that is the correct approach to do what I want because when trying to connect with a vue app I am running on localhost in Chrome I get Failed to connect extension not installed error
This is the provider script:
// Verus Web Wallet Provider Implementation
export const createVerusProvider = () => ({
  isVerusWallet: true,
  version: '1.0.0',
  _isConnected: false,
  _address: null,
  _listeners: new Map(),
  _connecting: null,
  
  // Request account access (legacy method)
  requestAccounts: function() {
    console.log('requestAccounts called');
    return this.connect().then(result => [result.address]);
  },
  
  // Connect to the wallet (new method)
  connect: function() {
    console.log('connect called');
    
    // Return existing connection if already connected
    if (this._isConnected && this._address) {
      return Promise.resolve({ address: this._address });
    }
    
    // Return existing connection attempt if in progress
    if (this._connecting) {
      return this._connecting;
    }
    
    const that = this;
    this._connecting = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        window.removeEventListener('message', handler);
        reject(new Error('Connection request timed out'));
      }, 30000); // 30 second timeout
      
      function handler(event) {
        if (event.source !== window) return;
        if (event.data.type === 'VERUS_CONNECT_RESPONSE') {
          clearTimeout(timeoutId);
          window.removeEventListener('message', handler);
          
          if (event.data.error) {
            that._connecting = null;
            reject(new Error(event.data.error));
          } else {
            that._isConnected = true;
            that._address = event.data.result.address;
            that._emitEvent('connect', { address: event.data.result.address });
            resolve(event.data.result);
          }
        }
      }
      
      window.addEventListener('message', handler);
      window.postMessage({ type: 'VERUS_CONNECT_REQUEST' }, '*');
    }).finally(() => {
      this._connecting = null;
    });
    
    return this._connecting;
  },
  
  // Get connected account
  getAccount: function() {
    console.log('getAccount called');
    if (!this._isConnected) {
      throw new Error('Wallet not connected');
    }
    return Promise.resolve(this._address);
  },
  
  // Send transaction
  sendTransaction: function(params) {
    console.log('sendTransaction called');
    if (!this._isConnected) {
      throw new Error('Wallet not connected');
    }
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      window.addEventListener('message', function handler(event) {
        if (event.source !== window) return;
        if (event.data.type === 'VERUS_SEND_TRANSACTION_RESPONSE') {
          window.removeEventListener('message', handler);
          if (event.data.error) {
            reject(new Error(event.data.error));
          } else {
            resolve(event.data.result);
          }
        }
      });
      window.postMessage({
        type: 'VERUS_SEND_TRANSACTION_REQUEST',
        params
      }, '*');
    });
  },
  
  // Event handling
  on: function(eventName, callback) {
    console.log('on called:', eventName);
    if (!this._listeners.has(eventName)) {
      this._listeners.set(eventName, new Set());
    }
    this._listeners.get(eventName).add(callback);
  },
  
  off: function(eventName, callback) {
    console.log('off called:', eventName);
    if (this._listeners.has(eventName)) {
      this._listeners.get(eventName).delete(callback);
    }
  },
  
  _emitEvent: function(eventName, data) {
    console.log('_emitEvent called:', eventName, data);
    if (this._listeners.has(eventName)) {
      this._listeners.get(eventName).forEach(callback => {
        try {
          callback(data);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error in event listener:', error);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});

It is a MetaMask style wallet that I am working on for Layer 1 blockchain Verus:
In my other App this is how I am trying to connect with the extension:
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

export function useVerusWallet() {
    const address = ref(null);
    const isConnected = ref(false);
    const error = ref(null);

    // Check if Verus wallet is installed
    const checkWalletInstalled = () => {
        return window.isVerusWalletInstalled === true;
    };

    // Connect to wallet with timeout
    const connectWallet = async () => {
        try {
            if (!checkWalletInstalled()) {
                throw new Error('Verus Wallet extension not installed');
            }

            // Add timeout to the connection request
            const timeoutPromise = new Promise((_, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('Connection timeout')), 30000); // 30 second timeout
            });

            const connectionPromise = window.verus.requestAccounts();
            const accounts = await Promise.race([connectionPromise, timeoutPromise]);

            if (!accounts || accounts.length === 0) {
                throw new Error('No accounts found');
            }

            address.value = accounts[0];
            isConnected.value = true;
            error.value = null;
            return accounts[0];
        } catch (err) {
            error.value = err.message;
            isConnected.value = false;
            throw err;
        }
    };

    // Get current account
    const getAccount = async () => {
        try {
            if (!checkWalletInstalled()) {
                throw new Error('Verus Wallet extension not installed');
            }

            const accounts = await window.verus.getAccounts();
            if (!accounts || accounts.length === 0) {
                throw new Error('No accounts found');
            }

            address.value = accounts[0];
            isConnected.value = true;
            return accounts[0];
        } catch (err) {
            error.value = err.message;
            isConnected.value = false;
            throw err;
        }
    };

    // Listen for account changes
    onMounted(() => {
        if (checkWalletInstalled()) {
            // Check initial connection status
            window.verus.getAccounts().then(accounts => {
                if (accounts && accounts.length > 0) {
                    address.value = accounts[0];
                    isConnected.value = true;
                }
            }).catch(() => {
                isConnected.value = false;
            });

            // Listen for account changes
            window.verus.on('accountsChanged', (accounts) => {
                if (accounts && accounts.length > 0) {
                    address.value = accounts[0];
                    isConnected.value = true;
                } else {
                    address.value = null;
                    isConnected.value = false;
                }
            });

            // Listen for disconnect events
            window.verus.on('disconnect', () => {
                address.value = null;
                isConnected.value = false;
            });
        }
    });

    return {
        address,
        isConnected,
        error,
        connectWallet,
        getAccount,
        checkWalletInstalled
    };
}

